# How many mappings does a Restricted Cone NAT remember?

Tags: udp, nat, hole-punching

Say I'm behind a [Restricted Cone NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#Methods_of_translation) and I want to be able to receive a UDP message from some endpoint `EP-A` (of some PC on the internet not behind a NAT). I first send a UDP packet to that `EP-A` to punch a hole in the NAT.

This means that the NAT needs to remember the mapping:

`(My local endpoint, EP-A)`

But what happens when I send another UDP packet to another remote endpoint `EP-B`? Will the new mapping `(My local endpoint, EP-B)` overwrite the old one? Or will the NAT remember both?

If the NAT is capable of remembering more than one such mapping, then what is the maximum?

I understand that this may differ from one NAT to another, thus if there isn't an RFC for it I'd be also very interested in any statistics, "recommendations for NAT manufacturers",...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the new mapping (My local endpoint, EP-B) overwrite the old one?

No.

> Or will the NAT remember both?

Generally yes. Upon saturation is will usually keep the old ones and drop new mappings, possibly with an ICMP error.

> If the NAT is capable of remembering more than one such mapping, then what is the maximum?

Implementation-dependent and often configurable if you have access to the system.

> thus if there isn't an RFC for it I'd be also very interested in any statistics

There actually are several RFCs for NAT, [4787](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4787) specifically refers to NAT in the case of UDP. But they do not specify concrete numbers, as it depends a lot on the equipment and network sizes.

In my personal experience running a UDP-based DHT node or a DNS resolver can be sufficient overwhelm the default configuration of a home router (custom firmware can alleviate this problem) or CGNATs that do not implement EIMs.

I remember reading some research paper that investigate the mapping retention time, port numbering behavior and mapping type of NATs across various ISPs, but I don't recall whether they also tested saturation.

Comment: Thanks! Would you happen to know an approximate number of the max number of mappings on an average home router (in order of magnitude)?

Comment: for one example: dd-wrt (3rd party linux based firmware) has a 4k limit by default and from my experience stock firmware can be lower than that. also, the table size is not the only limit. the timeout matters too if the udp application does many short-lived exchanges to different IPs. since unlike TCP the NAT can't know when the connection is closed

Comment: 4k doesn't seem too bad, my worry was that it would be up to about 256 or such. Still, it's probably less than those 4k on cheap $30 devices.